# Ajax POST method not working asp.net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have asp net core application with this controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using NewsletterWebsiteSample.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NewsletterWebsiteSample.Controllers
{
    public class GalleryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public GalleryController(IHostingEnvironment he)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = he;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            ErrorViewModel em = new ErrorViewModel();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads\\Images");
            foreach (string file in files)
                list.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));

            em.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            return View("Empty", em);
        }
    }
}
```

and when i manually go to that page it works and return json string in page but when i try to get that from my `js` file my ajax return error. Here is code i use when getting it

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Gallery/GetAll",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont get it. Your url is GetAll but your action method is Post ? And also you return view ?

Comment: Well i am new to this. So i guess my controller method is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to return list of file name in json format ? So I will change your code into this

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        ErrorViewModel em = new ErrorViewModel();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads\\Images");
        foreach (string file in files)
            list.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));

        return Json(list);
    }
```

And your ajax code

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Gallery/GetAll",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

Please let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 1):

in the mvc core, you should don't say `dataType: "json"`.
please type this :

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Gallery/GetAll",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific why i should or shouldn't do that.

Comment: when I use `dataType: "json"`, I have many errors in my project. after erasing correct all of them.
I tested this lot of time.
I don't know but I think default send was json.